# gulp concatenation with root and subfolders

Tags: gulp, build-process, gulp-watch, gulp-concat

I've the following gulp build process in place.

```
gulp.task("watch", function(){
    gulp.watch("public/admin/js/**/*.js", ["login"]);
}

gulp.task("login", function() {
    var js = [
        "!public/admin/js/api",
        "public/admin/js/*.js",
        "public/admin/js/controller/**/*.js",
        "public/admin/js/model/**/*.js",
        "public/admin/js/view/**/*.js"
    ];
    gulp.src(js)
        .pipe(concat("app.min.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("public/admin/js"));
});
```

1) I'm unable to add files that are in the root. `public/admin/js/*.js`, is not working

2) I feel there's a bit of duplication involved, if someone can please help me rewrite this. In short I want to concatenate all under `/public/admin` minus `/public/admin/api`

**P.S.** and of course don't wanna include `app.min.js` again from the last build which is of course will be on the root.

**P.P.S** I've this build process repeated for several project folders over and over again, any ideas for re-using this logic. right now I'm setting up different watches for each folder and building their app.min.js.

Answer (score 0):

"public/admin/js/" is repeated and im betting those aren't the only tasks that use it. In which case why don't you set it as a global variable via module.exports in your own config file? That way you can require it and set it to $ in which case your tasks will look something like:

```
module.exports.JSadmin = "public/admin/js/"

var $ = require('./globalConfig');

gulp.task("watch", function(){
    gulp.watch($.JSadmin + "**/*.js", ["login"]);
}
```

and for your other task you could create a dynamic array by looping through and appending the base directory, then using that array for your src as normal.

Not being able to add files in root, i believe its because you're exclusion statement is first (can't remember why), furthermore it is not necessary since you're stating which subdirectories to use in your array.

Check [glob syntax](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) for more info.

Comment: Can you please look into 1) and 2)